# Why *STDERR in this perl test is empty?

Tags: perl, testing, stderr, mojolicious

I have the following chunk of code copied from Mojolicious (mojo/log.t).
The application which I am testing does `$app->log->warn('whatever');`.
Unfortunately when I run the test as part of `make test`, STDERR happens to be empty. When I run it with `prove -lv t/basic.t` it succeeds. What's wrong with my program. Full source code of the tested program is [here](https://github.com/kberov/Mojolicious-Plugin-RoutesConfig)
Thank you!

```
my $buffer = '';
{
  open my $handle, '>', \$buffer;
  local *STDERR = $handle;
  require Blog;
  my $blog = Blog->new;
  $blog->startup();
}
like $buffer, qr/"routes" key must point to an ARRAY/,
  'right warning about ARRAY reference';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Edited]
You may need to set the environment variable `MOJO_LOG_LEVEL` to `warn`.
The way Mojo checks the level of logging is such that `$ENV{MOJO_LOG_LEVEL}` (`fatal` by default if using Test::Mojo) has the priority over the level set in the app.

I used version 7.59 of Mojolicious to check these things.

Comment: But log is already an attribute of the `$app`. and I am using it.
```
  $app->log->warn(  '"routes" key must point to an ARRAY reference '
                  . 'of routes descriptions'
                  . $file_msg . '...')
```
https://github.com/kberov/Mojolicious-Plugin-RoutesConfig/blob/master/lib/Mojolicious/Plugin/RoutesConfig.pm

Comment: Yes you are right, I edited the answer. Consider checking the other things

Comment: Setting `local $ENV{MOJO_LOG_LEVEL} = 'warn';` did the job. Thank you, wolfrevokcats!

Comment: Glad to hear that. I've asked about `SUPER::Register` because of my own tinkering with the code. I'll remove that from the answer.

Comment: One important clarification, which actually explains why setting MOJO_LOG_LEVEL was needed.
I found in the Mojo::Log source:
`$ENV{MOJO_LOG_LEVEL} ||= $ENV{HARNESS_IS_VERBOSE} ? 'debug' : 'fatal';`